# RabbitMQ: mapping a message to class using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have 2 different microservices that communicate through rabbit. The first microservice has the logic of the publisher and I was requested to create the consumer to consume the messages ih the queue, all this in a new microservice.

What I've done so far is the service class of the consumer like this:

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQService {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQService.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${peopleevents.queue}")
    public void receivedMessage(@Payload Country country) {
        logger.info("Received message is.. " + country.toString());
        System.out.println(country);
    }
```

But I don't know how to map what I get in the payload in a proper class.

My config class is as follows:

```
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class MQConfig {


    @Value("${peopleevents.queue}")
    public String queue;

    @Value("${peopleevents.exchange}")
    public String exchange;

    @Value("${peopleevents.routingkey}")
    public String routingKey;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.addresses}")
    private String address;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.vhost}")
    private String vHost;


    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queue, true, false, false);
    }


    @Bean
    Exchange myExchange() {
        return ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange(exchange).durable(true).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(queue)
                .to(exchange)
                .with(routingKey);
    }

    
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws IOException {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setAddresses(address);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(vHost);
        connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() throws IOException {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The AMQP message contains a `byte[]` for its body. So make it converted to that `Country`, you must provide a respective converter. See `messageConverter` attribute of the `@RabbitListener`. Or provide a global bean and Spring Boot's auto-configuration will set it into the `RabbitListenerContainerFactory`.

See more in docs about conversions: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#message-converters

Comment: Hi Artem! I've updated the post, I think that I already have that messageConverter method-

Comment: Yes, `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` is a good choice. The producer may serialize to JSON, and consumer can deserialize. The docs I've mentioned has all the information how to deal with types and so.